# how to access child nodes of a json file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

hi am parsing an api link at

```
https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2019-09-07&end_date=2019-09-07&api_key=DEMO_KEY
```

I am trying to do a console.log for required column names such as (id and name)

This is what I have initially tried to do this

```
var http = require('https');
var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2019-09-07&end_date=2019-09-07&api_key=DEMO_KEY';

http.get(url, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var mars = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", mars.near_earth_objects.name);
        

       
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

But I keep getting an undefined error

but when I try to access the whole json from this

```
var http = require('https');
var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2019-09-07&end_date=2019-09-07&api_key=DEMO_KEY';

http.get(url, function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var mars = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", mars.near_earth_objects);
        
  

       
    });
}).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

[image: screenshot for result]

I can see the name, id amongst the child nodes of the json result

Please how do I properly access the name and id column data

Comment: `near_earth_objects` seems to be an array. Consult the duplicate on how to work with arrays.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `axios` or `got` or `request` packages?